# django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column "role" of relation "APP_profile" does not exist

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, postgresql, django-models

Currently, I am facing the above-mentioned error when I am trying to execute the command

```py
python3 manage.py migrate
```

I cannot figure out the issue and the posts on Stackoverflow suggest to delete the migrations and recreate it, which I did. But I still face the same issue.

Please find below some code:

**models.py:**

```py
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models
from bokeh.themes import default
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.utils import timezone

# Create your models here.
class Project(models.Model):
    REQUEST_STATUS = (
        ('Pending', 'Pending'),
        ('Approved', 'Approved'),
        ('Denied', 'Denied'),
    )

    form_type = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False, null=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now())
    status = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=REQUEST_STATUS, default='Pending')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)

class Profile(models.Model):
    NORMAL = 1
    APPROVER = 2
    REVIEWER = 3
    ROLE_CHOICES = (
        (NORMAL, 'Normal'),
        (APPROVER, 'Approver'),
        (REVIEWER, 'Reviewer'),
    )
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    role = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=ROLE_CHOICES, null=True, blank=True)   
    def __str__(self):  # __unicode__ for Python 2
        return self.user.username


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_or_update_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
    instance.profile.save()
```

**admin.py:**

```py
from django.contrib import admin

# Register your models here.
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from .models import Profile, Project

admin.AdminSite.site_url = '/MyProject'
class ProfileInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Profile
    can_delete = False
    verbose_name_plural = 'Sites'
    fk_name = 'user'


class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    inlines = (ProfileInline, )
    list_display = ('id', 'username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'is_staff', 'get_role')
    list_select_related = ('profile', )

    def get_role(self, instance):
        return instance.profile.role
    get_role.short_description = 'Role'

    def get_inline_instances(self, request, obj=None):
        if not obj:
            return list()
        return super(CustomUserAdmin, self).get_inline_instances(request, obj)


admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, CustomUserAdmin)

admin.site.register(Project)
```

**urls.py:**

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include, re_path
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('APP.urls')),
    re_path(r'^APP/admin/', admin.site.urls, name='admin'),
    re_path(r'^logoutview/admin/', admin.site.urls, name='admin'),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT) + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

**settings.py:**

```py
....
# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    #'default': {
        #'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        #'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    #}
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'app_db',
        'HOST': '/Applications/djangostack-2.0.2-3/postgresql',
        'PORT': '5432',
        'USER': 'app_user',
       'PASSWORD': '**********'
    }
}
....
```

Here's my traceback:

```
File "/Applications/djangostack-2.0.2-3/apps/django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Django-2.0.2-py3.6.egg/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: column "role" does not exist
LINE 1: ...l_profile" ALTER COLUMN "role" TYPE integer USING "role"::in...
                                                             ^


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Applications/djangostack-2.0.2-3/apps/django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Django-2.0.2-py3.6.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Applications/djangostack-2.0.2-3/apps/django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Django-2.0.2-py3.6.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 365, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Applications/djangostack-2.0.2-3/apps/django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Django-2.0.2-py3.6.egg/django/core/management/base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Applications/djangostack-2.0.2-3/apps/django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Django-2.0.2-py3.6.egg/django/core/management/base.py", line 335, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Applications/djangostack-2.0.2-3/apps/django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Django-2.0.2-py3.6.egg/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 200, in handle
    fake_initial=fake_initial,
  File "/Applications/djangostack-2.0.2-3/apps/django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Django-2.0.2-py3.6.egg/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 117, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/Applications/djangostack-2.0.2-3/apps/django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Django-2.0.2-py3.6.egg/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/Applications/djangostack-2.0.2-3/apps/django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Django-2.0.2-py3.6.egg/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 244, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/Applications/djangostack-2.0.2-3/apps/django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Django-2.0.2-py3.6.egg/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 122, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "/Applications/djangostack-2.0.2-3/apps/django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Django-2.0.2-py3.6.egg/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 216, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.alter_field(from_model, from_field, to_field)
  File "/Applications/djangostack-2.0.2-3/apps/django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Django-2.0.2-py3.6.egg/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 509, in alter_field
    old_db_params, new_db_params, strict)
  File "/Applications/djangostack-2.0.2-3/apps/django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Django-2.0.2-py3.6.egg/django/db/backends/postgresql/schema.py", line 122, in _alter_field
    new_db_params, strict,
  File "/Applications/djangostack-2.0.2-3/apps/django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Django-2.0.2-py3.6.egg/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 650, in _alter_field
    params,
  File "/Applications/djangostack-2.0.2-3/apps/django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Django-2.0.2-py3.6.egg/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 117, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Applications/djangostack-2.0.2-3/apps/django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Django-2.0.2-py3.6.egg/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 100, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/Applications/djangostack-2.0.2-3/apps/django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Django-2.0.2-py3.6.egg/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 68, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/Applications/djangostack-2.0.2-3/apps/django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Django-2.0.2-py3.6.egg/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/Applications/djangostack-2.0.2-3/apps/django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Django-2.0.2-py3.6.egg/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Applications/djangostack-2.0.2-3/apps/django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Django-2.0.2-py3.6.egg/django/db/utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/Applications/djangostack-2.0.2-3/apps/django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Django-2.0.2-py3.6.egg/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column "role" does not exist
LINE 1: ...l_profile" ALTER COLUMN "role" TYPE integer USING "role"::in...
                                                            ^
```

Any help or advice will be appreciated! I will be more than happy to provide any further code or information needed. Thanks in advance for all the support and help.

Regards,

Amey Kelekar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First login to postgres database and select `app_db`
Then delete the row from `django_migrations` which is related to `role` column.

Then run `makemigrations` and `migrate` command respectively.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I just went a step ahead and deleted the table `Profile` instead of deleting the column `role`. But I believe your solution is sufficient enough to resolve my issue.

Answer (score 2):

**You may be having the same error persisting and several unapplied migrations under the same app. In that case do;**

```
yourApp$./manage.py makemigrations
yourApp$./manage.py showmigrations
# delete unapplied migrations indicated by empty [] before name of the file
yourApp$./manage.py migrate --fake
```

After doing this the app may look to be working but still the column may not exist in the database. You may realize this when you try to do a POST to the db. If the error arises again, **delete** the migration involved with role field both from **migrations folder** in the code and from **django_migrations table** in the database, then do migrations->migrate

```
yourComp$sudo -u postgres psql
postgres=#\c yourdb_name;
your_db=#select * from django_migrations;
# identify the id of the migration affecting 'role' column
your_db=#delete from django_migrations where id=3;
your_db=#delete from django_migrations where id=4;
```

Delete the same migrations from the code and do;

```
 (venv)yourApp$./manage.py makemigrations appname
 (venv)youApp$./manage.py migrate appname
```

Comment: Every now and again, I get a 'stuck' migration that Django doesn't pick up. Some combination of 1) faking the migrations, and 2) deleting/recreating the field always gets things going again.